# SKProductsRequest does not return SKProductsResponse in Catalyst app

Tags: ios, macos, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, mac-catalyst

I have an existing iOS app that contains in-app purchases.  I've done the following to port it to macoS,

1. built in Xcode by adding Mac as a target.
2. added a macOS platform to the existing app on App Store Connect.  I did not upload a macOS version yet.
3. completely log out of App Store.
4. run app from Finder.  I also tested running from the command line to see if there were any console messages that popped up.

As you can imagine, I create an SKProductsRequest object and call start().  Whereas the iOS version comes back fine, the macOS version does not return anything (or at least it's not returning a SKProductsResponse through productsRequest).

I am hoping there's some minor setting in App Store Connect or in my build that I'm missing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having this issue as well. Fine on iPad, nothing on Mac (catalyst)

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. I had to add a strong reference to my `SKProductsRequest` for it to return when building/testing for Mac. For iOS, it didn't ever need the strong reference to work.

[This post is basically the same issue with an answer in Swift.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61802978/in-app-purchase-on-mac-catalyst-not-working)

Comment: following up on this.  it seems to be the solution for most but I had already been using a strong reference.  i gave it a few months to simmer, assuming it may be an xcode issue.  same issue persists.