# In App Purchase on Mac Catalyst Not Working

Tags: swift, macos, in-app-purchase, storekit, mac-catalyst

In app purchases work fine for my iOS side of things. The data from StoreKit is populated as it should. The same code doesn't work on the Mac Catalyst version of the project. I have even created a listing for my Mac app on App Store connect with different bundle identifiers for the in app purchases. I have a print function that returns what product StoreKit found, it works well on iOS, but results with nothing when using Mac Catalyst.

Here is what I have done:

1. Make sure that In App purchases has been added in the capabilities section.
2. Make sure the Store Kit framework has been imported.
3. Make sure the bundle identifiers are correct.
4. Make sure all agreements are filled out.
5. I am signed out of the Mac App Store.

Code that works on iOS but not on MacOS:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)


    let productIds: Set<String> = ["..."]
    var request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIds)
    request.delegate = self
    request.start()
}

  func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    print("Loaded")

    for product in response.products {
        print("What came: \(product.productIdentifier) \(product.localizedTitle) \(product.price.floatValue)")}
```

The iOS app will return with the Product Identifier, Title and Price. The Mac app will return with nothing at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem. I had not created a strong reference to my product request.

This line of code fixed my issue:

```
var request: SKProductsRequest!
```

Comment: Worked for me as well.

Comment: This answer solved the problem for me as well in the sandbox environment, but after publishing my app, the Review Team said the problem still occurred for them. This nightmare problem seemed to be resolved by going into App Store Connect and uncheck 'Clear for Sale' for my In App Purchase and then Save. Then re-check it and save again.

Comment: In my case iOS app is working, while macCatalyst is working on my sandbox tester environment, but it is not working for the apple review team, the app is not receiving purchase confirmation from App Store or purchase confirmation is storing in keychain and this is only for MacCatalyst