# appropriate way to test macos Catalyst app with in-app purchases?

Tags: ios, macos, in-app-purchase, mac-catalyst

I am finding trouble figuring out how to test a port of an app with in-app purchases from iOS to macOS using Catalyst and universal purchases.  The iOS app—including IAP—is on the AppStore, having been tested on a physical device, since the simulator cannot test IAP.

Compiling for a macOS target, when disconnected from the network, everything works fine, since it's not communicating with the AppStore for IAP.  When on the network, I've tried running directly in Xcode (see [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61397691/skproductsrequest-does-not-return-skproductsresponse-in-catalyst-app)), through Finder, and the command line (always on my dev machine).  I have successfully uploaded a macOS build the AppStore. About 5% of the time the macOS app will run, although I've only started—never finished—restoring a purchase made on the iOS app.  I have tried all manner of deleting files and rebooting the dev machine.  All contracts are signed and I have strong references for all of the necessary bits of the StoreKit.
Still no consistent behavior for testing.

Is there documentation *anywhere* about testing in this sort of situation?  Thanks!